# How to access SQL Server Analysis Service instance through vpn

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas

My computer is the host of SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS). I also created a VPN server on my local machine, so my analysis services instance can be accessed remotely over internet. VPN server is working properly.

I created another administrator in SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) instance which Is the VPN user accessing my network. Now, I want someone from another network to connect to my VPN Server (which is working fine), then access my SQL Server instance via SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) installed on the client's local machine.

How can I do this?

I hope you guys understand what I am trying to say.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the external user has authenticated on your domain via VPN, then they would connect (via SSMS) just like you would. Open the Connection Dialogue and select `Analysis Services` as the Server type. Enter the Server name and select Windows Authentication, then hit connect. Ta-da! *(This assumes the user has had their windows logic added as a login on SSAS, if they haven't, they need to be).*

Comment: Thanks Larnu, Act

Comment: Thanks Larnu, Actually, i tried this but on the Connection Dialogue the user already listed is not the VPN user and there is no option to change the user.

Comment: No, there won't be. When you connect via a VPN though, you *should* be authenticating as someone from the domain; this sounds likes they're not?

Comment: Yeah. But when I tried to access cube from client machine via Excel and in the dialog box I entered server name and in authentication I select from another user and then I put the credentials of VPN user and it got acces of cube.